# align only one type of content vertically

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been trying to make my own linktree, but i'm struggling with the positions of my content, I want to let my text fixed on the center and just change the position of the icon according to the size of the screen

```css
img {
  width: 5em;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  border: 0.15em solid white;
  border-radius: 5em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 21rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <ul>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <li>
        <img src="./img/last.fm.png" alt="Last.fm">
        <p>Last.fm</p>
      </li>
    </a>

    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <li>
        <img src="./img/MyAnimeList.png" alt="MyAnimeList">
        <p>MyAnimeList</p>
      </li>
    </a>

    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <li>
        <img src="./img/Backloggd.png" alt="Backloggd">
        <p>Backloggd</p>
      </li>
    </a>

    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <li>
        <img src="./img/Letterboxd.png" alt="Letterboxd">
        <p>Letterboxd</p>
      </li>
    </a>

    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <li>
        <img src="./img/MyDramaList.png" alt="MyDramaList">
        <p>MyDramaList</p>
      </li>
    </a>

    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <li>
        <img src="./img/Serializd.png" alt="Serializd">
        <p>Serializd</p>
      </li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</main>
```

I'll leave two images: how the page looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yKAQ.png

and how I want it to be:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLMU8.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQ2xY.png

Comment: aggh, don't use absolute unless you have to.  A better solution is to use flex on the links.  Add an invisible element the same size as your round images to the right and use   space-between on justify-content

Answer (score 2):

###### One possible solution - Keep label centered and use absolute for img

add these to your existing styles

```
img {
  ...
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; // Change this on screen size with media query
}

li {
   ... 
   position: relative;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Main problem:* you have a static `width: 21em;` defined on the main parent and content exceeding that width. Need children width defined.

Instead of a `width: 21em`, find a `width` based on the most amount of content if you have similar divs. I found that `250px` was a good spot based on the longest amount of text.

Next, define the children's width. Since you only have two children for each `li` I figured `li>* { width: 50%;}` would be best so they each take up half.

Finally, once you have done this you will have something that looks similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUFyX.png). I prefer using `padding` to achieve spacing from here. Also, if you like your text justified either left or right so you can use `gap` or `margin` to replace `text-align: center;`. That is all personal preference.

```css
body {
  background-color: #414042;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2em;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 35px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 10px 1.5em;
}

li>* {
  width: 50%;
}

a {
  width: 250px;
  border: 0.15em solid white;
  border-radius: 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <ul>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <li>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50/e1e1e1/000" alt="Last.fm">
        <p>Last.fm</p>
      </li>
    </a>

    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <li>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50/e1e1e1/000" alt="MyAnimeList">
        <p>MyAnimeList</p>
      </li>
    </a>

    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <li>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50/e1e1e1/000" alt="Backloggd">
        <p>Backlogged</p>
      </li>
    </a>

    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <li>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50/e1e1e1/000" alt="Letterboxd">
        <p>Letterboxed</p>
      </li>
    </a>

    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <li>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50/e1e1e1/000" alt="MyDramaList">
        <p>MyDramaList</p>
      </li>
    </a>

    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <li>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50/e1e1e1/000" alt="Serializd">
        <p>Serialized</p>
      </li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</main>
```